# How to close a true hole in model? The model is closed, but has an edge loop that creates a hole throught it

Tags: sculpting

I have a 3D scan that I'm fixing in the Sculpt mode. My problem, I filled all holes that made the object unclosed.

But now I have a few actual holes, as in the geometry is "valid"? When I sculpt the edge loop always stays there, so I can only make the hole smaller.
I tried to add a sphere with a Boolean modifier to fill the space, but that resulted in some weird internal geometry that messed the model up. Any ideas on how to close this?

Thanks!

PS: Sorry if the answer is already here somewhere, I tried googling it, really!
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]

Comment: @Mikolas I think you have mistakenly created two different accounts with the same name: user IDs 64415 (who asked the question) and 64416 (who edited it afterwards). If you want to fix this, please go to the ["contact us" page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to fill the holes with ctrl F > Grid Fills?

[image]

Comment: I believe the user is dealing with a *topological* hole: he needs to transform "the donut into a disk"

Answer (score 1):

I just "solved" it. It's a pretty bad solution, but it works...
In wireframe I selected all the holes. Deleted the verticies. Then I let Blender to automatically fill the holes (Space - Fill holes)
[image: Imgur]
[image: Imgur]